# How to tell amount of usable memory in executors

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark executors use some of the memory for caching (`spark.storage.memoryFraction`) and some of the memory for shuffle (`spark.shuffle.memoryFraction`). The rest is available for use by the application code, for example that runs in an `RDD.map` operation.

I'd like to know the amount of this usable memory. (I want to have large partitions that still fit in memory. I want to divide the data size by the usable memory per partition to get the number of partitions.)

Here's how I calculate this:

```
val numExecutors = sc.getExecutorStorageStatus.size - 1 // Exclude driver.
val totalCores = numExecutors * numCoresPerExecutor
val cacheMemory = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.values.map(_._1).sum
val conf = sc.getConf
val cacheFraction = conf.getDouble("spark.storage.memoryFraction", 0.6)
val shuffleFraction = conf.getDouble("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", 0.2)
val workFraction = 1.0 - cacheFraction - shuffleFraction
val workMemory = workFraction * cacheMemory / cacheFraction
val workMemoryPerCore = workMemory / totalCores
```

I'm sure you'll agree this is terrible. The worst part is that if the defaults change in Spark, my result will be incorrect. But the defaults are hard-coded in Spark. I have no way to get at them.

Is there a better way to get `workMemoryPerCore`?

Comment: For all the memoryFraction you could reflect your way into sc.env (SparkEnv), get the *Managers and invoke the getMaxMemory on each of them. The code to do this will be very ugly though.

Comment: Just as a side note: that might not be the most ideal way of determining the number of partitions to use for your data.It is common to use smaller sized partitions rather than trying to maximize the size of each partition, that way if a computation needs to be recomputed the size is smaller. Of course you don't wall a lot of really small partitions either since the overhead will be expensive.

Comment: @Holden: I agree. But which partition is "small" and which is "large" depends on how much memory is usable on the executors. And sometimes (in a latency sensitive situation) we want exactly as many partitions as executor threads, to minimize overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the max memory available to the application is determined (using the default values) like this:

```
  private def getMaxMemory(conf: SparkConf): Long = {
    val memoryFraction = conf.getDouble("spark.storage.memoryFraction", 0.6)
    val safetyFraction = conf.getDouble("spark.storage.safetyFraction", 0.9)
    (Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory * memoryFraction * safetyFraction).toLong
  }
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala#L1227

This is how I have previously calculated application memory - although not particularly stringently:

For example, if the spark.executor.memory = 4g

```
4 x 0.6 x 0.9 = 2.16g
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's the memory available for the RDD cache. So this memory may be used up by the cache and not available for the application. Spark uses memory for the RDD cache and for shuffle. I want to get the size of the memory that Spark has no explicit claim on.

Comment: Not sure this deserves a downvote - This is literally how Spark calculates the memory available to the application at run-time.

Comment: This is how it calculates the memory available to the BlockManager. If you increase `spark.storage.memoryFraction` this number will increase, while the memory available for other purposes decreases.